# SQL escaping not working

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to insert some json into mysql

```
UPDATE `table` 
SET `value`= '["14\" Square"' 
WHERE `entity_id` = '1';
```

But when I select the value I get `["14" Square"` instead of `["14\" Square"` just wondering how to force the `\` to not be escaped thanks.

Comment: Just use "14\\" - EDIT oops I think haim770 beat me to it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use double slash:

```
UPDATE `table` 
SET `value`= '["14\\" Square"' 
WHERE `entity_id` = '1';
```